Hi, please i have a error server on nuxt 3 ssr test e2e
I am working on a project in nuxt 3 ssr, it is absolutely not necessary for js to be executed on the client side, so I work a lot with the server, in the code below I call my store which itself calls my service, but every time I get a connection refusal error; I tried several methods found on the friends platform none of them worked, I work with node 20 if that helps.
import { AccountService, Activate2FaResponseDTO, OpenAPI, Pgp2FactorAuthenticationDTO } from "~/services/market-place";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig(event);
  OpenAPI.BASE = config.public.restApiBaseUrl;
 console.log("OpenAPI.BASE",   OpenAPI.BASE);
  const body = await readBody(event);
  const { publicKey } = body;

  if (!isPgpKey(publicKey)) {
    return sendRedirect(event, "/pgp/SendPgpKey?error=true");
  } else if (isPgpKey(publicKey)) {
    console.log("okay bro");

    const data: Pgp2FactorAuthenticationDTO = { publicKey };
    console.log(data);

    const response: Activate2FaResponseDTO = await AccountService.create2FaAuthentication({
      requestBody: data
    });

    if (response && response.sessionId && response.encryptedCode) {
      console.log("Service response:", JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
      return response;
    } else {
      return sendRedirect(event, "/pgp/SendPgpKey?error=true");
    }
  } else {
    return sendRedirect(event, "/pgp/SendPgpKey?error=true");
  }
  
});```

 this is error : ***ERROR  [nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:28960 ***


Hm maybe stick to Nitro or something else if you really don't need any client-side code. Otherwise, the latest LTS is Node v22. Besides that, since it's a 500 error, the issue is on the server side, try to check the logs in the console or alike. Also, I recommend trying to use https://hoppscotch.io/ to debug the whole situation by trying it out with your endpoint.

thank kissu,  i'm  doing the e2e test in this case but my question is to know if there is a special configuration or a call to the server file to be made in nuxt.config for example, during the initialization of the project?

Hence why I'm proposing to go step by step and do things in a simpler context to be able to troubleshoot more easily. Also we need more debugging material here to help you.
